# (How to manipulate)Poker Positioning using ENUM

Tags: java, enums, poker

Let's say I created the following class:

```
public enum Position {

   Dealer(1), //1
   SB(2),     //2
   BB(3),     //3
   UTG(4),    //4
   UTG1(5),   //5
   UTG2(6),   //6
   UTG3(7),   //7
   HJ(8),     //8
   CO(9);     //9

   //Constructor
   int code;

   Position(int code) {
     this.code = code;
   }
}
```

How do I manipulate ENUM by using the numbers in parenthesis? 
For example, in my Poker Table class, I initiate new players. Each player passes the parameter Position.
So initially,

```
player[1].getPosition() = Dealer  
player[2].getPosition() = SB  
player[3].getPosition() = BB   
etc etc etc
```

After the hand is over, all the positions need to be shifted over by one.
    So player[1] needs to have the  CO(9) position.
    player[2] needs to have the Dealer(1) position.
    player[3] needs to have the SB(2) position.
    etc etc

I understand that I can just make a for loop with a variable cycling through the numbers 1 through 9, but how do I access the position based on the integer inside the PositionENUM?

---

EDIT:
I already have the getters and setters.

```
    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
```

However the getters and the setters do not provide me with the correctly change the Positions of the players each round.

After every betting round, I need to change the Position of each player, so I need to figure out how to shift the ENUM Position of each player after each betting round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to choose an enum instance based on the value of its code. You can use a static `Map<Integer, Position>` to do this. The only gotcha is that it has to be housed in a static inner class:

```
public enum Position {

    ...

    Position(int code) {
        this.code = code;
        MapHolder.BY_CODE.put(code, this);
    }

    private static class MapHolder {
        private static final Map<Integer, Position> BY_CODE = new HashMap<Integer, Position>();
    }

    public static Position findByCode(int code) {
        return MapHolder.BY_CODE.get(code);
    }
```

I'd also recommend delegating the logic of picking the next position to the enum itself. Just add this method to the `Position` enum:

```
public Position nextPosition() {
     return findByCode((this.code + 1) % Position.values().length);
}
```

Then, your client code can simply go:

```
for (Player player : players) {
    player.setPosition(player.getPosition().nextPosition());
}
```

Comment: Ahh yes, the logic of this inner class seems to make sense. Clever way of creating a hashmap to bind the ENUM to their integers inside.

Too bad there was not an easier/simpler way of manipulating the ENUM with the numbers inside.

Comment: Yeah, as far as I know java doesn't have an easier way of mapping enum instances by a member field value. 
Actually for this specific case, since you're interested in just the order and not the actual integer values, Ray's solution may be a better choice.

Comment: What's all this static map stuff? They are numbered 1 to n, so just use Enum.ordinal() + 1!

Answer (score 1):

Look here is an [onlinepoker](http://www.bonusonusbonus.pl) game sample

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cctype>
#include <memory.h>
#include "logic.h"

using namespace std;
// & means location
// * value of location

struct Cards {

enum Value {Two = 2, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace};
Value V;
int Suite;
enum Suite {Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs, Spades};
};

struct Hand {
Cards [5];

};

struct Deck {
Cards [52];

};

char * personsName [20]; //this means location with *
int numNames = 0;
char * Name;
char * search;
bool Continue;

int main ()
{
do {
for(int x = 0; x < 20; x++){
cout << "Enter a name, type END to stop: ";
Name = readString ();

if(strcmp (Name, "END") != 0){
personsName [x] = Name;
numNames++;
}
else{
Continue = (strcmp (Name, "END") != 0);
break;
}

}
cout << "Pre-sorted Names" << endl;
printNames(personsName,numNames);

bubbleSort(personsName,numNames);

cout << "Post-sorted Names" << endl;
printNames(personsName,numNames);

cout << "What would you like to find?" << endl;
search = readString();
cout << "The name is at index " << binarySearch(personsName,search,numNames) << endl;

} while (Continue);
delete [] * personsName;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but you can declare a `getCode()` method for your enum:

```
public enum Position {

  Dealer(1), //1
  SB(2),     //2
  BB(3),     //3
  UTG(4),    //4
  UTG1(5),   //5
  UTG2(6),   //6
  UTG3(7),   //7
  HJ(8),     //8
  CO(9);     //9

  int code;

  //Constructor
  Position(int code) {
    this.code = code;
  }

  public int getCode() {
    return code;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`code` is package access scope.

If you are calling from within the package, then you may do a

```
Position.BB.code
```

If you are calling from outside the package, then you may need to provide an accessor inside the enum class.

```
public int getCode(){
    return this.code;
}
```

Comment: I am calling it from the package, but I do not want to write   
    Position.BB.code   
    Position.SB.code etc..

I need a method that returns the ENUM based on number inside

Answer (score 0):

you could just use the ordinal() for the position (starts at 0 like subscripts). also it might be easier if the enums were in reverse order (since the deal passes to the left) like the code below. this will not work in a short game (you would need to do a modulo the number of players).

```
enum Position {
    Dealer, CO, HJ, UTG3, UTG2, UTG, BB, SS;
    Position next() {
        return values()[(ordinal() + 1) % values().length];
    }
}
class Player {
    Player(Position position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
    void next() {
        position = position.next();
    }
    Position position;
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player[] players = new Player[Position.values().length];
        for (Position position : Position.values())
            players[position.ordinal()] = new Player(position);
        for (Player player : players)
            System.out.println(player.position);
        for (int i = 0; i < Position.values().length; i++)
            for (Player player : players)
                player.next();
        for (Player player : players)
            System.out.println(player.position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is your requirement.See if the code given below helps :

```
public enum Position {

    Dealer(1), // 1
    SB(2), // 2
    BB(3), // 3
    UTG(4), // 4
    UTG1(5), // 5
    UTG2(6), // 6
    UTG3(7), // 7
    HJ(8), // 8
    CO(9); // 9

    // Constructor
    int code;

    Position(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    private static Position[] currentPosition = Position.values();

    public static Position[] getCurrentPosition() {
        return currentPosition;
    }

    private static List<Position> positionWrap = Arrays.asList(currentPosition);

    public static void shiftPostion() {
        Collections.rotate(positionWrap, 1);
        updatePositions();
    }

    private static void updatePositions() {
        for (int i = 0; i < currentPosition.length; i++){
            currentPosition[i].code = i + 1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Position[] pos = getCurrentPosition();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pos));
        Position.shiftPostion();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pos));
        Position.shiftPostion();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pos));

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return this.name() + "(" + code + ")";
    }
}
```